# Printing a string multiple times in a textbox C#

Tags: c#, string, textbox

I'm trying to print a string inside a text box n times.
I can make the textbox display the string with:

```
    string textinput = inputTEXT.Text;
    int intinput = int.Parse(inputINT.Text);

    int n = 0;
    while (n < intinput)
    {
         output.Text = textinput;
         n++;
    }
```

But i wish to make it so that, for n amount of times, the string is printed, then moves to the next line and prints it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is just setting `output.Text` over and over again.  You'll need to *append* the value onto the end:

```
{output.Text += textinput; n++;}
```

Notice, the `+=` operator, which is short hand for:

```
output.Text = output.Text + textinput;
```

If you wanted a *new line* after each iteration, you'd do:

```
{output.Text += textinput + System.Environment.NewLine; n++;}
```

This of course assumes whatever `output` is can display multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what += is doing, this works fine, however i wish to print one string per line? This gives for example when textinput is "hello": hellohellohellohellohello

EDIT: I see now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your while loop, change the code to

```
output.Text += textInput
```

that would do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

```
output.Text += textInput + Environment.NewLine
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to append to the previous value of the output textbox and be sure to have a multiline textbox otherwise you will see only one long line

```
// No need to convert a string to a string (Text property is already a string)
string textinput = inputTEXT.Text;
int intinput;
// Do not trust the user to type an integer here... 
// check with tryparse...
if(Int32.TryParse(inputINT.Text, out intinput))
{
    int n = 0;
    while (n < intinput)
    {
       output.AppendText(textinput + Environment.NewLine); 
       n++;
    }
}
else
   MessageBox.Show("Not an integer");
```

Comment: "output.appendtext
This brings the error: cannot assign to appendtext because it is a method group

Comment: AppendText is a method of the TextBox class. It is more appropriate to use this method instead of a string concatenation because it use the internal SendMessage API to concatenate the strings. Instead string concatenation on the C# side will result in a new string built and rebuilt for every append.